# Adding a mounted volume to python's `sys.path`

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

Is there any reason for me to avoid adding a mounted volume to an OS' PYTHONPATH?

I want to create a way for a container to always have the same packages installed on it even if the image has been updated or the container was deleted somehow.

The only way I could think of doing it was to add a volume to it with an "external" site-packages which is a mounted directory on the server.

Technically it works (albeit a bit slow).
I just wanted to know if there is any implications I'm possibly not thinking about.

Thanks